# How to change text of y-axes on a matplotlib generated picture

Tags: matplotlib

The page is
"http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html"

Let's look at the y-axis, the numbers there do not make any sense, could we change it to something else that is meaningful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except the cumulative distribution plot, and the last one, the rest of the y-axes data show normalized histogram values with normed=1 keyword set (i.e., the are underneath the histogram equals to 1 as in the definition of a probability density function (PDF))

Answer (score 0):

You can use yticks(), see this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html?highlight=yticks).